# Use arrays to add up values based on the title or the alt attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, math

Calculating form has options and based on what the client enters determines what products load in a sidebar. Products are given a quantity that directly reflects that value of the option.

So now per product there is a Total Price, Total Duration and Total Number of Dives as seen here.

```
num1=Number(document.getElementById('product_quantity_' + productid).value);
num2=Number(document.getElementById('product_price_' + productid).value);
nums=num1*num2;
document.getElementById('product_price_total_' + productid).value = nums;

num1=Number(document.getElementById('product_quantity_' + productid).value);
num2=Number(document.getElementById('product_duration_' + productid).value);
nums=num1*num2;
document.getElementById('product_duration_total_' + productid).value = nums;

num1=Number(document.getElementById('product_quantity_' + productid).value);
num2=Number(document.getElementById('product_dives_' + productid).value);
nums=num1*num2;
document.getElementById('product_dives_total_' + productid).value = nums;

num1=Number(document.getElementById('product_quantity_' + productid).value);
num2=Number(document.getElementById('product_hire_' + productid).value);
nums=num1*num2;
document.getElementById('product_hire_total_' + productid).value = nums;
```

So now we need a script that gives us the Grand Total Price of all of the  -- 'product_price_total_' + productid).value -- and another for Grand Total Duration, and a third for Grand Total Dives etc.. etc...

Not sure how but a few ideas would be an array that added up only fields with a specific alt tag or title tag.

Anyone got any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Do have an array of your product id's you could loop through?

Comment: The problem is that the product id's are driven by CMS ID's and I don't want to list them as every time one adds a new product one would have to alter the code as well. Unless there is a way to list all ids that exist which there may well be. Assuming we had all the product id's, how would the code look? thanks.

ps. If you were referring to the + product id in the code above that comes from the individual product code that runs this function like this 
<script type="text/javascript">
product_totals('PRI_<?php the_ID(); ?>');
</script>

Comment: Your code obviously has redundancy issues. You know that, right?

Comment: You will have to forgive me on that. If there is a better way of doing this I would like to know. If you see its implementation that may clear a few things up. http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adventure-training/#level_01 and click on beginners then use the checkboxes

Comment: Instead of using so many hidden fields, try sending a JSON object with the product info from the server to the UI.  Then all you need to do is get the product IDs, look up the values and calculate.  If you still need to pass complex data back to the server, then pass the JSON objects back in a hidden field and parse them on the server.  You can also use AJAX to call a server method to process the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?
(Using the same $() function as Šime Vidas above)

```
var productIds = {};

function product_totals(id) {
    productIds[id] = true; // store all id's as the totals are calculated
    ....
}

function totalTotals() {
    var totalPriceTotal = 0;
    var totalDurationTotal = 0;
    var totalDivesTotal = 0;
    var totalHireTotal = 0;

    for (var id in productIds) {
        // multiply by 1 to make sure it's a number
        totalPriceTotal += $('product_price_total_' + id).value*1;
        totalDurationTotal += $('product_duration_total_' + id).value*1;
        totalDivesTotal += $('product_dives_total_' + id).value*1;
        totalHireTotal += $('product_hire_total_' + id).value*1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your code all implememnted in the answer above. There is still one problem though. If you view the implementation at http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adventure-training/#  and click on beginners.   Once you have loaded in all the ajax by clicking on the checkboxes if you then uncheck a box the script activated by 'test' no longer works. Any ideas.

Comment: When I click on the 'test' link I'm getting an error saying that totalTotals() is not defined. If you defined it within a jQuery function you will probably want to bind that function to the link you are using. Otherwise it will not be available in the global scope. So instead of onclick="totalTotals(); return false", try this right after you define totalTotals: $('#testLink').click(function() { totalTotals(); return false; });

Comment: I was modifying the code that is why it did not work. I believe the problem is with the way the code counts the product IDs. As when a product is loaded out (ie. its option box is unchecked and the product is loaded out via ajax) It would appear that it is still in the initial count of product IDs and therefore the script is not adjusting and recalculating. Try it for yourself by ticking a box and then unticking it. Any Thoughts?

Comment: every time you uncheck something you will need to delete that id from the productIds object (delete productIds[id];)

Answer (score 0):

Marvellous work chaps, thanks for you help. Very good team work here is the full final code.

function product_analysis(address, box) {
    if (box.checked) {

```
$('#product_' + box.alt).load(address);

}
else {

$('#product_' + box.alt).load('http://www.divethegap.com/update/blank.html');

}
document.getElementById('product_quantity_PRI_' + box.alt).value = box.value;
```

};

var productIds = {};

function product_totals(id) {
    productIds[id] = true; // store all id's as the totals are calculated
    var quantity = $c('product_quantity_' + id).value;
    var price = $c('product_price_' + id).value;
    var duration = $c('product_duration_' + id).value;
    var dives = $c('product_dives_' + id).value;
    var hire = $c('product_hire_' + id).value;

```
Number($c('product_price_total_' + id).value = price * quantity);
Number($c('product_duration_total_' + id).value = duration * quantity);
Number($c('product_dives_total_' + id).value = dives * quantity);
Number($c('product_hire_total_' + id).value = hire * quantity);
function $c(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
```

}
}

function totalTotals() {
    var totalPriceTotal = 0;
    var totalDurationTotal = 0;
    var totalDivesTotal = 0;
    var totalHireTotal = 0;

```
for (var id in productIds) {
    // multiply by 1 to make sure it's a number
    totalPriceTotal += $c('product_price_total_' + id).value*1;
    totalDurationTotal += $c('product_duration_total_' + id).value*1;
    totalDivesTotal += $c('product_dives_total_' + id).value*1;
    totalHireTotal += $c('product_hire_total_' + id).value*1;
}
$c('GT_total_price').value = totalPriceTotal;
$c('GT_total_duration').value = totalDurationTotal;
$c('GT_total_dives').value = totalDivesTotal;
$c('GT_total_hire').value = totalHireTotal;

function $c(id) {
return document.getElementById(id);
```

}

}

Comment: If you are using jQuery, you can just do $('#GT_total_price').value instead of using $c('GT_total_price') function and so forth for the other ones. The $c function is redundant if using jQuery.